# How to explode nested json in pandas as rows?

Tags: python, pandas

My json looks like below,

```
{
   "customer_name":"john",
   "phone":{
      "mobile":000, 
      "office":111
   },
   "mail":{
      "office":"john@office.com", 
      "personal":"john@home.com"
   }
}
```

phone or mail can have 1 or many items. Also, the key (office, mobile, personnel) are not same always. For example, it can be Business or alternative. So I wanted to convert them to rows and not columns. Most of the questions are to convert to columns so not able to find a solution for rows.

The final data frame should look like,

```
customer_name   |   phone.key   |   phone.val   |  mail.key   |   mail.value 
john            |   mobile      |   000         |             | 
john            |   office      |   111         |             |         
john            |               |               |  office     |   john@office.com
john            |               |               |  personal   |   john@home.com
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yiu can change format of nested dictionaries added `customer_name` with new `key`s:

```
d = {
   "customer_name":"john",
   "phone":{
      "mobile":000, 
      "office":111
   },
   "mail":{
      "office":"john@office.com", 
      "personal":"john@home.com"
   }
}

out = []
for k, v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        for k1, v1 in v.items():
            out.append({'customer_name':d['customer_name'],f'{k}.key': k1,f'{k}.value':v1})
```

Least comprehension alternative:

```
out = [{'customer_name':d['customer_name'],f'{k}.key': k1,f'{k}.value':v1} 
        for k, v in d.items() if isinstance(v, dict) for k1, v1 in v.items()]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(out)
print (df)
  customer_name phone.key  phone.value  mail.key       mail.value
0          john    mobile          0.0       NaN              NaN
1          john    office        111.0       NaN              NaN
2          john       NaN          NaN    office  john@office.com
3          john       NaN          NaN  personal    john@home.com
```

Comment: Can you can't do this json_normalize?

Comment: @ScottBoston - Ya, like first step yes, but then is necessary next processing.

Answer (score 4):

It would be way simpler if you use `json_normalize` in the following way to flatten your data:

```
 from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
 data = {
  "customer_name":"john",
  "phone":{
     "mobile":000, 
     "office":111
   },
  "mail":{
    "office":"john@office.com", 
    "personal":"john@home.com"
   }
 }

 df = json_normalize(data)
```

Comment: Only output not matched what need @Selva