How to transfor complex json structure into a dataframe or parquet file
I need a help.
I have the next json example
json_sample
And I need to convert the json input into a dataframe using pyspark to save later into parquet file.
I try with:
json_path = 's3://df-julio-poc/source/my_test.json'

df0 = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").option("encoding", "UTF-8").json(json_path)
df0.count()

df = spark.read.json(json_path)
df.printSchema()
df.show()

And the result must be something like:

Which is the best way to create this dataframe in this way?
Regards

This question is similar to: How to convert complex JSON to dataframe by using PySpark?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

One way to achieve result is using
pyspark.sql.functions.explode

You can explode the data filed and navigate to each section easily. Example for accessing id,Name,owner,card_temp you can do something like below
    val df0 = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").option("encoding", "UTF-8").json("C:\\Users\\\Downloads\\my_test.json")

    df0.printSchema()

    val lowcaseDF = df0
      .withColumn("data_elements", explode(col("data")))
      .withColumn("card_elements", explode(col("data_elements.card")))
      .select(col("data_elements.name"),col("data_elements.id"),col("data_elements.owner"),col("card_elements.temp"))

    lowcaseDF.show() 

Above is scala spark code but you can do it in pyspark also and get below result.
+--------------------+-------+-------+--------+
|                name|     id|  owner|    temp|
+--------------------+-------+-------+--------+
|               email|1384323|1019693|texto 23|
|               email|1384323|1019693|texto 32|
|               email|1384323|1019693|texto 43|
|      email_template|1384501|1019693| texto 3|
|      email_template|1384501|1019693| texto 2|
|email_template_qc__c|1384531|1019693| texto 1|
|email_template_qc__c|1384531|1019693| texto 2|
+--------------------+-------+-------+--------+

Similarly for all nested field you can navigate.

You can convert json dictionaries into columns using pandas' json_normalize
Then convert that into spark dataframe and insert it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61848067/3238085
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
 data = {
  "customer_name":"john",
  "phone":{
     "mobile":000, 
     "office":111
   },
  "mail":{
    "office":"john@office.com", 
    "personal":"john@home.com"
   }
 }

 df = json_normalize(data)

